# Usage of “because” for introducing insufficient reason (instead of reason)

Tags: conjunctions, negation, subordinate-clauses

Obviously, "because" introduces a subordinate clause to provide a reason (clause of reason) for the main clause "He is sad"  in the following sentence.

> 1. He is sad because he has mislaid his car keys.

but in this second sentence

> 2. He should not be sad because he has mislaid his car keys.

I think it does not provide a reason for "He should not be sad".

Am I right?

If I am right, what kind of clause does it introduce in the second sentence and how would it be understood?

Can we use "that" instead of "because" in the second sentence equivalently and interchangeably? I think "that" may be preferred.

Is the usage of "because" in the second sentence correct at all?

Comment: 2. is fine, though the interpretation is ambiguous. In one reading, the negative has scope over the adjunct; the adjunct will be in the same intonational phrase as "should not". We understand that "Mislaying his car keys should not cause him to be sad". An alternative, and less likely, interpretation is that the adjunct would form a separate intonational phrase (and in writing may well be preceded by a comma to remove the ambiguity). Here "mislaying his car keys" is unfortunate, but there is an implicature that there is some other reason that he should not to be sad.

Comment: It becomes a lot trickier if you change the sentence to one such as: **He should not be said because his mother in law has can't vist.**

Comment: How can that and because be equivalent? They can't. Period.  Both provide a reason, one for sad and one for not sad. I just don't think this is really an English question and would be the same in your language.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.

> He should not be sad because he lost his car keys

is grammatically correct. The “not” negates the whole sentence. The meaning is

> Losing his car keys should be considered an insufficient reason for him to be sad.

Comment: What kind of clause does "because" introduce in here? Clause of insufficient reason? Is there any specific name for such a clause in the English grammar?

Comment: First, “clause of cause” includes both reasoned and emotional motivations, human reasons. Do not interpret “cause” too narrowly. Second, the construction negates the entire sentence; the “not” negates the clause rather changes what kind of clause it is. “The book is not where I put it” does not change a clause of location into a different kind of clause.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is ambiguous: "He should not be sad because he lost his car keys" could either mean that losing his car keys is a good reason to *not be* sad, or that it is *not* a good enough reason to *be* sad. The second reading is more likely because we know that losing car keys could easily make one sad.

Moving the subordinate clause to the beginning makes the first reading more prominent:

- Because he lost his car keys, he should not be sad.

Adding emphasis, adding *just*, or rephrasing the negation makes the second reading more prominent:

- He should not be *sad* because he lost his car keys (he should actually feel some other emotion).
- He should not be sad *because he lost his car keys* (but perhaps he should be sad for another reason).
- He should not be sad **just** because he lost his car keys.
- It is not the case that [he should be sad because he lost his car keys].

In both readings it is a subordinate clause of reason. In the first reading, you can think of it as modifying "should not be sad". In the second reading, you can think of it as just modifying "be sad", and "not" as modifying "should".

Comment: The technical term for this is scope of negation ambiguity. Another example: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/what-is-the-scope-of-negation

Comment: Can we also eliminate ambiguity by changing "because" in the second sentence into "that"?

Comment: Yes, "He should not be sad that he lost his car keys" is nearly equivalent to "He should not be sad about losing his car keys".